# Probability Question: Rolling two dice with re-roll

Tags: probability, combinatorics, dice

I came across the following dice-roll problem:

- You roll two dice consecutively. Rolling a 6, then a 6 wins you \$100.
- Rolling a 6, then not a 6 loses \$x
- For all other cases you, redo the dice rolling.
- When should you play the game?

If X is the value amount I receive by playing this game; that event A: (6,6); event B: (6, not 6); I calculated the expected value E[X] as follows:

E[X] = P(A)*100 - P(B)*x = $\frac{100}{36} - \frac{5x}{36}$. E[X] is positive when $5x < 100$. I should therefore play the game when $x< \$20$.

Am I missing something by not taking into account the "re-roll" information? Does that change my probabilities, or can it just be treated as the following independent re-running of the game?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can just assume the first roll is $6$ because you reroll anything else.  It becomes a single roll with $+100$ on a $6$ and $-20$ on anything else, which is fair.

Comment: Great, thanks! Very helpful